# Javascript Array Push breaks loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following Typescript class, with it's Click function, which is triggered by a button click, in my mobile app. The bit of interest is the `todoItemTable.read`, which goes and gets an array of ToDoItems from my cloud backend. The current code works and spits out the text of 8 todo items, but I want to store the text in an array, so if you see the commented out line where I push into `todos`, that was how I thought I woula pproach the issue. However, that line of code stos the loop running, so I get the first ToDo item logged twice and then nothing else. The application does't hang and there is no error.

```
export class HelloWorldModel extends Observable {
  public todos: any[]; 

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  Click() {
    var client = new MobileServiceClient("https://example.azurewebsites.net");
    console.log("CLIENT");
    var todoItemTable = client.getTable("TodoItem");
    console.log("Table");
    this.todos = [];
    todoItemTable.read<TodoItem>().then(function (results) {
      // results is array of TodoItem-s
      console.log(results.length);
      console.log(results[0].text);
      for (let i of results) {
        console.log(i.text);
        //this.todos.push(i.text);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To work with the same scope use arrow functions, like this:

```
todoItemTable.read<TodoItem>().then((results) => {
  for (let i of results) {
    this.todos.push(i.text);
  }
});
```

See [the Mozilla Developer Network on Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem, whenever I tried using `array.push()` anywhere in my `loop` it would run through once and then stop. I fixed this problem by instantiating the array as an empty array `(array: string[ ] = [ ]`) OUTSIDE of my `loop`. then instantiating the new string to be pushed to the array INSIDE the loop.
hope this helps anyone out there =)